# Receive details from Paypal when user buys an item

Tags: php, paypal

I have a little shop which works with Paypal (each item has a Paypal button with price).

I would like the system to return users to my website after they have bought an item in Paypal so that he or she will receive details about:

- himself (name, address, country...)
- the item which he bought (name + price which he paid).

How can I do it? I don't have really experience with Paypal...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start here https://www.x.com/community/ppx/dev-tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign up at https://developer.paypal.com/ and access their API for your transactions.

You can use PHP to do this via the NVP (Name Value Pairs) documentation and examples they provide.

Be prepared to spend a log time on this, PayPal is bad. It is slow and things that should work often do not or do work but not as expected.